# Does `printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` invoke undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, standards, undefined-behavior

### According to [the standards](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) :

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After
>   the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> - Zero or more flags [...].
> - An optional minimum field width. [...]
> - **An optional precision that gives [...] the maximum number of bytes to be written for s conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed by [...] an optional decimal integer;**
> - An optional length modifier [...].  +  A conversion specifier character [...].
> - An optional minimum field width. [...]
> - A conversion specifier character [...].

Later :

> A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were
>   omitted.

### What I would expect from `printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` according to how I interpret the standard definition :

The second quote I took from the standard suggests that we could pass a negative precision argument and that such precision would be ignored.

So, `printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` should be equivalent to `printf("%s\n", "foo")`, which would display `"foo\n"` and return `4`.

### Yet, here is the actual `printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` behaviour on the system I use (osx) :

`printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` displays `" \n"` and returns `2`.

This is obviously different from what I was expecting.

- Is somehow my interpretation of the standards wrong?
- Is this behaviour undefined?
- Is passing a negative precision (edit: without asterisk) actually possible?

Comment: With `int n = printf("%.-1s\n", "foo");` MSVC issues a compiler warning about unknown format, the code prints `-1s\n` and `printf` returns `4`.

Comment: I think the part about a negative argument is only talking about the case where you use `*` to get the value from an argument, rather than putting the precision in the format string.

Comment: @WeatherVane About the `"%-1s\n` format string : Yes, but in such case this is not a negative precision but a `-` flag and a `1` minimum length field. Yet the standards talks about "negative precision".

Comment: I am reading the standard as you are and tending to think `gcc` is not conforming with this one... Or they have some different interpretation.

Comment: The standard also explicitly mentions *non-negative* field width, but the precision being "a decimal integer" (which includes negative numbers)...

Comment: You omitted the relevant part of 7.21.6.1p5: "As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision. … A negative field width argument is taken as a - flag followed by a positive field width. A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted." So the part about the negative value is **clearly** related to a parameter passed, not a decimal in the string itself. When reading a standard, **all** words are important!

Comment: @Barmar That could be that! `printf("%.*s\n", -1, "foo")` indeed displays `"foo\n"` and returns `4`.

Comment: That should be `printf("%.*s\n", -1, "foo")`

Comment: @Olaf Then what should happen if neither is `*`?

Comment: @Barmar Corrected, my bad.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: 7.21.6.1p9 is very clear: "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined." That does not disallow the library can define the behaviour. But that's beyond the C standard and in general not a good idea (unless it is way too useful to be ignored;-).

Comment: @Olaf But is it really invalid? The precision field is "decimal integer". Not necessarily positive.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: You **are** aware `-10` is actually two tokens: one unary operator `-` plus a decimal integer constant of type `int`? A sign is not a "decimal value". That's why it is explicitly mentioned as flag and for a negative field-width argument (using `*`).

Comment: @Olaf I agree with this part, but how is a negative precision field invalid according to the standard? Does the "an optional decimal integer" part exclude negative fields?

Comment: @vmonteco: Again: a "decimal integer" does not include a sign! It does not even make sense, that's why it is explicitly mentioned for a argument field-width to be invalid (because there a negative value cannot be made invalid).

Comment: To finally close this (I'm not very hopefull it will, though): **Which good would a negative precision argument do?**

Comment: @Olaf The standard is mentioning in several places "decimal integer", "non-negative decimal integer" and "signed decimal integer". So it looks like there can be "negative" and "signed" ones.

Comment: @Olaf This part precisely sounds ambiguous to me. To me an integer representation implicitly includes negative integer representations unless "nonnegative" is explicitly mentionned.

Comment: @vmonteco: How about reading my comment above? "-10` is **not** anm integer constant, but an expression with an operator. I don't see what's unclear. If you are language-lawyering, you need to read and understand the standard correctly and know the overal conventions, not only of a particular field. That's beyond what this site is meant to do. Finally: **Why the heX do you want to do this anyway? It has no use**

Comment: @Olaf I did read this comment, but with all due respect, it's not obvious since -as Eugene stated- some integer fields are defined as "nonnegative".

Comment: @Olaf - From where in the standard do you have that a "decimal integer" can't be a negative value? The "field width" is described as "nonnegative decimal integer" while "precision" is described as just "decimal integer". From that I would expect that a "decimal integer" can be negative and therefore include a sign. That said, I have no idea what a negative precision should mean, nor why anyone would use it.

Comment: @4386427: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638909/does-printf-1s-n-foo-invoke-undefined-behaviour?noredirect=1#comment76265305_44639592 and the following comment.

Comment: @vmonteco my comment was a simple report of what MSVC does. If you wanted to display `foo\n` why did you use that rigmarole?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm actually trying to implement my own printf with this standard (for studies purpose) but I didn't get the system's implementation behaviour with some precise and weird cases.

Comment: If `printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` is good then so is `printf("%.+1s\n", "foo")`.  I then wonder  about `printf("%.000000000000001s\n", "foo")` or `printf("%.9999999999999999s\n", "foo")`

Comment: @chux: I would not expect implementations to have any problem leading zeroes.  A more interesting question would be whether implementations should be expected to include the code necessary to yield defined behavior for the second scenario since doing so would increase the size of every program that uses `printf`.

Comment: @supercat An environmental limit in the spec that effectively limits `printf()`:  (§7.21.6.1 "The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095." So insane buffer lengths are UB, yet the _parsing_ of the format seems to be able to cap _decimal integer_ at the "at least 4095" level or so.

Comment: @chux: Using `printf("%.4097s",bigLongString);` could overflow the buffer if `bigLongString` is more than 4095 characters long, but shouldn't overflow the buffer if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is somehow my interpretation of the standards wrong?

I take your interpretation to be summed up by this:

> So, `printf("%.-1s\n", "foo")` should be equivalent to `printf("%s\n",
>   "foo")`, which would display `"foo\n"` and return 4.

No. The provision you quote about negative precision *arguments* being ignored does not apply to this case.  That provision is talking about the option of specifying the precision as `*` in the format string, and passing the value as a separate `printf` argument:

```
printf("%.*s\n", -1, "foo");
```

In that case, the negative precision argument causes `printf()` to behave as if no precision was specified.  Your case is different.

On the other hand, the standard does not here require the precision value appearing in the format string to be a *nonnegative* decimal integer.  It does qualify the term "decimal integer" that way in several other places, including earlier in the same section, but it does not do so in the paragraph about the precision field.

> - Is this behaviour undefined?

No.  There are two conflicting interpretations of the required semantics (see next), but either way, the standard defines the behavior.  It could be interpreted either as

- the behavior described for a negative precision argument also applies when a negative precision value is presented directly in the format string.  This has the advantage of consistency, and it is the behavior you report observing.  However,
- a literal reading of the standard would indicate that when the precision is presented as a negative decimal integer in the format string, then the ordinary semantics described in that section apply; for `s` directives, that would be that the negative precision expresses the maximum number of characters to be output.

The behavior you observe is not consistent with the former interpretation, but given the practical difficulties in outputting fewer than 0 bytes, it comes as little surprise to me that the latter interpretation is not successfully implemented.  I'm inclined to guess that the latter is what your implementation is trying to implement.

I suspect that it was an unintentional omission at some stage to leave open the possibility of providing a negative value for the precision field, but intentional or not, the standard seems to allow it.

Comment: I think neither of the interpretations are actually observed here... https://ideone.com/UTvjoM

Comment: I don't agree the standard allows it. Agreed, not using the "nonnegative" for the precision can be considered a flaw. However, the field-width is a bad analogy, as the `-` flag would make it _look like_ a negative value. Allowing a negative field-width (and interpreting it as a `-` flag plus a nmon-negative field-width with the `*` argument supports this. Looking at other places in the standard, Looking over the wall, 6.4.4.2p3 (floating point constants) "… the digit sequence in the exponent part is interpreted as a decimal integer …" is clearly about a non-negative, ie.e. digit-only value.

Comment: "_the behavior described for a negative precision argument also applies when a negative precision value is presented directly in the format string. This has the advantage of consistency, and it is the behavior you report observing._"
Actually, that's precisely the case I was expecting but not observing.

Comment: … additionally, integer constants are always positive. A sign is treated as a unary operator, it is not part of the constant. Tthat's why for e.g.16 bit `int` `#define INT_MIN -32768` yields a wrong type (`unsigned int`, instead of `int`).

Comment: @Olaf, The "decimal integer" term used here is not referring to integer constants (as the standard elsewhere uses that term).  If the standard meant the same thing it would use the same term.  Moreover, the usage of the "decimal integer" term elsewhere in the standard in conjunction with qualifiers on its signedness (especially "nonnegative") counterindicates the proposition that when unqualified, the term should be interpreted as disallowing negative numbers.

Comment: You are right, @EugeneSh.. I have corrected the answer in this regard.

Comment: " If the standard meant the same thing it would use the same term" - Because it never was unclear or had flaws? Considering the defect reports for C11 already (not to mention the previous revisions) and the fact that at least the one about `volatile` has already been reported for C99, I tend to disagree. Also the fact it **is** used for clearly positive value only for floats contradicts you. Anyway, as a negative precision does not make sense at all (that's why it is ignored for a variable argument), I'll leave it at that. Some things are worth discussing, other not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Olaf - I really doubt that a "decimal integer" in the standard refers to a non-negative value. There are place where it is explicit stated that the "decimal integer" must be "unsigned" or "nonnegative". Why do that if "decimal integer" is always nonnegative"? Further the description of conversion specifier d says "Matches an optionally **signed** decimal integer". I rather think that they forgot to include the "nonnegative" a couple of places.

Comment: @4386427: In order for an implementation of `printf` to regard `%12.-5f` as equivalent to `%12f`, it would need to include code to recognize a `-` sign which followed the period as an indicator that it should ignore any digits before the next format specifier.  If it takes 40 bytes of code to accomplish that, support for such a feature would add 40 bytes to just about *every* program that uses `printf`, whether or not it needs that functionality.  Would that feature have enough value to justify adding 40 bytes to every program that uses printf?  I think not.

Comment: @supercat Was that comment intended for me? If so I'm not sure why. I have not commented on `printf` and `precision`. My comment was on whether the term "decimal integer" in the standard **always** means a non-negative value as another user claims in a comment.

Comment: @4386427: Regardless of how the term is used elsewhere in the Standard, I am unaware of any rationale given for imposing the costs associated with inclusive treatment here.

Comment: @supercat - Sorry, but I really have no idea what you are talking about. It seems unrelated to any of my comments.

Answer (score 4):

N1570-§7.21.6.1/p5:

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, **may be indicated by an asterisk**. **In this case**, *an int argument supplies the field width or precision*. The arguments specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the argument (if any) to be converted. A negative field width argument is taken as a - flag followed by a positive field width. **A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted**.

Standard specifies that this is applicable only when asterisk is used as precision in the format string and a negative value is passed as an argument as given below

```
printf("%.*s\n", -1, "foo");  // -1 will be ignored
```

In the 4th para it says:

> [...] The precision takes the form of a period (`.`) followed either by an
>   asterisk `*` (described later) or by an optional **decimal integer**; [...]

but it doesn't specifically says whether decimal integer should be greater than `0` (as it says in case of field width of `scanf` in the section 7.21.6.2/p3). Standard seem ambiguous at this point and result may be machine dependent.

Comment: @EugeneSh.; For the time being I agreed, but the fact is standard explicitly specifies -ve precision as an argument in case of `*` is used after `.` in a format string.

Comment: Even if the standard still sounds ambiguous about this, your answer and the interpretation you gave seem to be _de facto_ confirmed by some tests : negative precision field doesn't seem accepted as valid and therefore seem to invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EugeneSh.;  That came to my mind because my mind was not willing to accept that such thing even exist and I relate it to real numbers. I removed that part.

Comment: (But if it seems to be the case on the system I actually use, it may not be the case for other implementations I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

In a format like `"%-5d"`, the width isn't -5; instead, the - sign is a "flag character", which indicates that a value should be left-aligned in a field of the given width.  The use of "non-negative" for the width ties in with the fact that a "-" is a flag character rather than a sign.  While the Standard doesn't specify that the precision must be non-negative, it's hard to imagine any non-contrived purpose that would be served by saying that an implementation which encounters a "-" between a period and some decimal digits must ignore the content of those digits.  It's possible that some implementations might process things that way, but it's likely that many implementations don't have any code to explicitly handle a "-" in that position and would either treat it the same as a "-" at the start of the format or regard it like any other character without a defined meaning, depending upon which was more convenient.  I see no reason to regard either behavior as "defective".

Comment: Should the format get constructed at run time: `sprintf(format, "%%.%ds", some_int);`, it would be nice if `printf(format, "Hello_World");` not invoke UB, regardless of `some_int`.  Yet that is a bit of a contrived situation as could have used `sprintf(format, "%%.%us", some_unsigned)`

Comment: @chux: A number of implementations define meanings for format strings beyond those mandated by the Standard; if an implementation uses `%@d` as a special format that takes a `char*` containing the characters to use for digits 0-9 but code passes something other than a `char*`, all manner of chaos could result.  The Standard makes no attempt to distinguish situations where implementations might reasonably implement some deliberate useful behavior that could go wrong if code's not expecting it, versus those which should behave in more constrained fashion.